# Search and display three dropdownlists with search button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a search function with 3 DropDownLists and a search button. How will I display it on the same page?

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //read sql server connection string from web.config file
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccreString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("emed_province");

            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM emed_province ORDER BY PROVINCE_NAME ASC", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                adptr.Fill(dt);
            }

            ddlProvince.DataSource = dt;
            ddlProvince.DataTextField = "PROVINCE_NAME";
            ddlProvince.DataValueField = "PROVINCE_CODE";
            ddlProvince.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlProvince_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccreString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("emed_province");

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            PROVINCE_CODE = '" + ddlProvince.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM emed_city WHERE PROVINCE_CODE =@pcode", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", ddlProvince.SelectedValue);
            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            adptr.Fill(dt);

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@pcode";
            param.Value = ddlProvince;

            comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
        ddlCity.DataSource = dt;
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "CITY_NAME";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CITY_CODE";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccreString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("emed_city");

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
        PROVINCE_CODE = '" + ddlProvince.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM emed_doctors_hospitals     WHERE CITY_CODE =@ccode", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccode", ddlCity.SelectedValue);
            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            adptr.Fill(dt);

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@ccode";
            param.Value = ddlCity;

            comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
        ddlSched.DataSource = dt;
        ddlSched.DataTextField = "SCHEDULE";
        ddlSched.DataValueField = "HOSPITAL_CODE";
        ddlSched.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

When someone selects a value in the DropDownList and hits the button, it will display the lists of doctors available in the province, city and per particular schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check this sample. I have used SQLDatasource with SelectParameters for this example (you
   can replace it with your own object datasource, custom binding etc.) [SQLDataSource Select Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx)
2. The second dropdownlist automatically populates when the first dropdownlist is changed
3. On Button even I am just selecting the currently selected values of each dropdownlist (You can select your doctor list in the same way)

ASPX

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Cascading DropDown.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Cascading_DropDown" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server">
    <title></title> </head> <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label>
            Category:</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True"
            DataSourceID="sdsCategory" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryID"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <label>
            Products:</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsProducts" DataTextField="ProductName"
            DataValueField="ProductID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search Prodcut" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblSelectedValues" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsCategory" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName] FROM [Categories] ORDER BY [CategoryName]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsProducts" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName] FROM [Alphabetical list of products] WHERE ([CategoryID] = @CategoryID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategories" Name="CategoryID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form> </body> </html>
```

.CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void ddlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlCategories.SelectedValue == "")
    {
        ddlProducts.Items.Clear();
        ddlProducts.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSelectedValues.Text = "You selected Category:" + ddlCategories.SelectedItem.Text + " & prodcut:" + ddlProducts.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

You can drop a gridview on form like Abel said & on your button click event, fetch each drop down list selected value & execute your query & databaind your gridview like you are already doing with your drop down lists.

Comment: @user1230147 if you liked my answer you can click the upvote arrow. Also you can mark it as answer if it helped you for your problem, Damien.

Answer (score 0):

All you essentially need to do is to place the controls in the ASPX page declaratively:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlSche" runat="server" />
```

You can calculate the results in the Page_Load using `ddlSched.SelectedValue` and similar methods.

Essentially, you use the button's onclick handler for this type of thing:. But since you already have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event, it seems that you're on the right track. It's fired when the user postbacks the page and the index was changed (or, in other words, the user selected something else than the current selection in the DropDownList).

Comment: forgot to mention that i'm still new to asp.net and c#.. a pretty dumb question, how will i do that? i mean, onclick, it will display the available doctors in terms of selected values on the dropdownlists..

Comment: @user1230147: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't know your datamodel, so I cannot help you with your actual query. From the code that you showed, it seems that you already have quite something in place to make a search. You seem to be missing an `Execute` method after `comm.parameters.add` and something like a `GridView` or `ListView` that you can bind the result data to. This binding follows the same concept as you currently do with the DropDownLists.

Comment: yes, that's what i mean. i don't actually know how to make the data display. my intention is, when the user selects the value on the dropdownlist and hit the search button, it will display a list/table of available doctors.

Comment: @user1230147 your best bet is to have a look at some ListView or GridView tutorials. It's not easily answered in two or three lines on a Q/A site like this. Here's one: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx. Using the Visual Studio GUI it's actually quite easy to do this yourself, just follow the instructions.